# KSH Mathemathical operation doesn't return the result in decimal, but a 0

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I'm writing a script that has to calculate some numbers.
One part of it is the Percentage calculation, where is my main issue.
I have two numbers: `num1=272700 and num2=2592000.`
I need to calculate (num1/num2)*100.

```
percentage=$((($num1/$num2)*100))
echo $percentage

Result: 0.
```

And if I do

```
num3=$(($num1/$num2))
echo $num3
Result:0
```

My desired result is: **10.52 (%)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much depends on your version of ksh.

Search on your operating system for ksh93 which will support floating point arithmetic (sometimes ksh93 is present in addition to older ksh), and if ksh93 is present you can put at the start of your script `#!/bin/ksh93` or `#!/usr/bin/ksh93` (or whatever is the correct path or use `#!env ksh93` etc).

Later versions of ksh support floating point arithmetic. By default all the arithmetic is integer unless you tell it to use floating point arithmetic when declaring the variables.

If (and only if) your version of ksh is newer than the 11/16/88 build then the following syntax is accepted:

```
typeset -F num1=272700 num2=2592000
typeset -F2 percentage
(( percentage = (num1/num2)*100))
echo $percentage
```

When run on a suitable version of ksh, this yields 10.52

If your version of ksh does not support floating point arithmetic as above then you can shell out either to `bc` or `awk` or other tool to do the work, with resulting loss in performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I guess that the ksh version doesn't support floating point. But with I have managed to make it work with awk. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

```
$ awk -v n1=$num1 -v n2=$num2 ' BEGIN { print n1/n2*100 } '
10.5208
```

or

```
$ awk -v n1=$num1 -v n2=$num2 ' BEGIN { printf("%.2f\n", n1/n2*100 ) } '
10.52
```